# Apache with mod_mono - Failed to connect to mod-mono-server

Tags: linux, apache, mono, mod-mono

I'm trying to run mod_mono with apache but I can't get it to work. I need to run a web service (asmx) which need mono to run.

Right now I'm trying to run the test project that comes with mono just to try make mod_mono run with apache.

So far I couldn't get it to work and I've got some error at apache log files.

I was able to fix the error where it would say it couldn't find the directory of mono, but now I'm just getting without any additional information-

```
[error] Failed to connect to mod-mono-server after several attempts to spawn the process.
```

I have the test project from mono at /var/www/html/test

Here is my mod_mono.conf

```
<IfModule !mod_mono.c>
    LoadModule mono_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_mono.so
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Powered-By "Mono"
</IfModule>

AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx
AddType application/x-asp-net .asmx
AddType application/x-asp-net .ashx
AddType application/x-asp-net .asax
AddType application/x-asp-net .ascx
AddType application/x-asp-net .soap
AddType application/x-asp-net .rem
AddType application/x-asp-net .axd
AddType application/x-asp-net .cs
AddType application/x-asp-net .vb
AddType application/x-asp-net .master
AddType application/x-asp-net .sitemap
AddType application/x-asp-net .resources
AddType application/x-asp-net .skin
AddType application/x-asp-net .browser
AddType application/x-asp-net .webinfo
AddType application/x-asp-net .resx
AddType application/x-asp-net .licx
AddType application/x-asp-net .csproj
AddType application/x-asp-net .vbproj
AddType application/x-asp-net .config
AddType application/x-asp-net .Config
AddType application/x-asp-net .dll
DirectoryIndex index.aspx
DirectoryIndex Default.aspx
DirectoryIndex default.aspx

MonoAutoApplication enabled
MonoDebug false
MonoServerPath "/opt/mono/bin/mod-mono-server4"
MonoUnixSocket "/tmp/.mod_mono"
<Location "/Mono">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
        SetHandler mono-ctrl
</Location>
```

I've also added (since its at conf.d this shouldn't be needed but it is just in case)

```
Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_mono.conf
```

Comment: Try to run "mod-mono-server" in a console, see if it spits out an error.

Comment: i get this -bash: mod-mono-server: command not found , which doesn't make much sense since it is installed

Comment: try to install mono-devel & then check with mod-mono-server

Comment: I've run mod-mono-server from /opt/mono/bin and got this 
./mod-mono-server4
mod-mono-server4
mod-mono-server4
Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server
Root directory: /opt/mono/bin
Hit Return to stop the server.